# Using make file to create package inside nodejs monorepo

Tags: makefile

I'm new to using `Makefile`(s) and I'd like to create a command `make package <PACKAGE_NAME>`.

And I'd like it to run the following:

```
mkdir $PACKAGE_NAME
cd $PACKAGE_NAME
npm init -y
mkdir src
mkdir lib
mkdir test
```

I'm a little confused if I should put this in a shell script or If I can just have this directly in the make file itself (which is preferable), and I also am unsure how to have arguments in a `Makefile`.

Comment: Would `make package_<PACKAGE_NAME>` be acceptable? (Note the underscore.)

Comment: Hey @Beta I'd prefer it as a flag or as a proper argument, the underscore seems hacky, but I'm open to anything.

Comment: How about `make package PACKAGE_NAME=<PACKAGE_NAME>`?

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
package:
    mkdir $(PACKAGE_NAME)
    cd $(PACKAGE_NAME) ; npm init -y ; mkdir src lib test
```

The whitespace at the beginning of line 2 is a TAB, not four spaces. Likewise line 3.

Comment: I'm having trouble adding stuff to this, it seems sometimes files appear at the top level. https://gist.github.com/reggi/2e09ef9f181e3a9d1586c5c7dab54c7c

Comment: @ThomasReggi: Each line executes in its own sub-shell, so the `cd` applies only to that line (which is why I put those other commands in the same line). Try `touch $(PACKAGE_NAME)/lib/index.js` instead of `touch ./lib/index.js`.